# Use non-persisted fields in composed_of class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got credit card info in a Booking object that I can't store in the database because of PCI compliance. So a few of the fields I can save (customer's name), but a few I can't (card number, etc).

My question: how can I get the data that isn't persisted into my composed_of class (CreditCard, in this case).

I've tried adding:

```
attr_accessor :card_number
composed_of :credit_card, :mapping => [%w(card_number card_number), %w(first_name, first_name)]
```

to Booking.  The first_name flows through because it's a database column, but card_number does not.

Any suggestions on how to get this into the system correctly?  I can just go straight to the card I guess, but I feel like that's bound to result in some kind of hidden problems, since I'm:

1. adding mutability to a value object
2. circumventing whatever is going on behind the scenes

Any suggestions?